# There is there a way to have an editor for Robot Framework in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, robotframework

I'm looking for a way to code some Robot Framework test files (.robot) on Visual Studio 2013 but VS's Text Editor alone isn't good to code missing some color to code syntax for Keywords, Test Title, Tags, etc.. I'm currently using Python Extension on Visual Studio and I'm way more confortable on Visual Studio than Eclipse + PyDev.

Do you have any idea how we could install a Robot-Framework Editor Extension on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no publicly-available plugin for visual studio. It is possible to write one using visual studio APIs, though it's somewhat difficult. A team I worked on a few years back wrote a plugin for robot. Unfortunately, management wouldn't let us make it available as open source.

Comment: Any update on this matter? I am using VS 2017.

Comment: @SergeyKucher: I have no idea. I don't use visual studio.